# Вывод вложенного массива с ключом

Tags: php

```
 $arr = array(
 "222"=>array("Иванов", "Васечкин"), 
 "333"=>array("Петрова", "Кузьмин"), 
 "444"=>array("Иванова", "Попов"));
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
 echo "<br> Группа ".$key."<br> Студенты: ".$value;
}
```

Банальный вопрос, но не могу сообразить.

Comment: в цикле. **все** операции над массивами производятся в цикле. Это простое  правило сосем несложно запомнить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)** - Объединяет элементы массива в строку

```
$arr = array(
    "222"=>array("Иванов", "Васечкин"), 
    "333"=>array("Петрова", "Кузьмин"), 
    "444"=>array("Иванова", "Попов")
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo "<br> Группа ".$key."<br> Студенты: ".implode(', ', $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

implode хорошая  штука, но малополезен при необходимости html-оформления результатов. Более универсально выводить вложенным циклом:

```
$arr = array(
    "222"=>array("Иванов", "Васечкин"), 
    "333"=>array("Петрова", "Кузьмин"), 
    "444"=>array("Иванова", "Попов")
);

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    echo "Группа ".$key."<br> Студенты: ";
    foreach($value as $val){
        echo '<b>'.$val.'</b>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Просто в условии ничего не сказано про оформление и пр. Так что каждый implode тоже верно, т.к  решает задачу))